# Calling Ant ReplaceRegexp from TeamCity with strings including quotes and equalsigns

Tags: regex, ant, teamcity

I have an Ant file that contains targets used by my TeamCity configs. I have a target defined for this that uses replaceregexp:

> ```
>   <replaceregexp
>       file="${targetfile}"
>       match="${originalstring}"
>       replace="${updatedstring}"
>       byline="true"
>   />
> ```

I need to replace a string in my targetfile that already includes a set of doublequotes; specifically, I need to replace *minlevel="Trace"* with *minlevel="Warn"*. In TeamCity I call the Antfile with the following:

> -Doriginalstring=minlevel="Trace" 
>   -Dupdatedstring=minlevel="Warn"

but it ignores the doublequotes.
I'm sure there's a combination of escape characters I'm not understanding.
What would be the correct way to call this from TeamCity?
Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the property values in double quotes, and escape the literal quotes with backslashes.

> -Doriginalstring="minlevel=\"Trace\"" -Dupdatedstring="minlevel=\"Warn\""

Similarly for values with spaces in them:

> -Doriginalstring="minlevel=\"Trace\" db=\"M1Auth\"" -Dupdatedstring="minlevel=\"Warn\" db=\"M1Auth\""

Another solution is to save the properties in a file and pass it to the `ant` command via `-propertyfile <filename>` (see the [propertyfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) task and [Running Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)).

Comment: Thanks, that worked exactly as I needed.
Now I have a 2nd, related question. Another string that I need to update has an embedded space:
`-Doriginalstring=minlevel="Trace" db="M1Auth"
-Dupdatedstring=minlevel="Warn" db="M1Auth"`
I tried escaping the space with a backslash but it was still seen as two separate arguments. Any suggestions?

Comment: @TomT It's the same idea (answer updated). You need to wrap the whole value (including the space) inside outer quotes, and of course escape the inner quotes.

Comment: that's what I thought and tried earlier. However, the embedded space is being recognized as an indication that a new Ant target is being referenced.
Here's what I'm passing:
`-Doriginalstring="minlevel=\"Trace\" writeTo=\"AuthLogDb\"" -Dupdatedstring="minlevel=\"Warn\" writeTo=\"AuthLogDb\""`
and here's what TeamCity says:
`Target "writeTo="AuthLogDb""" does not exist in the project`
Any insights?
I do appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't know how the TeamCity config calls `ant` and how the `ant` executable exactly deals with such property values, but one thing you can try is passing the properties from a file.